# CUDA packages fail in Julia

Tags: julia

I've been trying to get started on GPU Programming in Julia. I have already installed the appropriate NVIDIA Drivers, CUDA Toolkit, NVCC etc. and have also added the cuda file to `PATH`. However when I try to `Pkg.test("CUDA")` or `Pkg.add("CuArrays")` I get the following errors respectively.

```
Testing Running tests...
error: Linking globals named '*Core.Intrinsics.bitcast#1': symbol multiply defined!
```

```
Resolving package versions...
ERROR: Unsatisfiable requirements detected for package CUDAapi [3895d2a7]:
 CUDAapi [3895d2a7] log:
 ├─possible versions are: 0.5.0-4.0.0 or uninstalled
 └─restricted by julia compatibility requirements to versions: uninstalled — no versions left
```

Here are my device details:

OS : Ubuntu LTS 22.04
NVIDIA Driver: 535.86.10
CUDA Version: 12.2
Julia Version 1.11.0-DEV.235 (2023-08-06)

Comment: What julia version?

Comment: @OscarSmith Julia ver. 1.11.0

Comment: yeah this is a known issue CUDA relies on some julia internals with how Julia deals with LLVM and some recent codegen changes have broken some of that. It will probably be fixed fairly soon. see https://github.com/JuliaGPU/GPUCompiler.jl/issues/489 for the bug report

Comment: @OscarSmith should I just downgrade Julia then?

Comment: yeah. 1.10 beta is working fine with CUDA (or even 1.11 from a few weeks ago)

Comment: theoretically https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/50791 might have fixed this. Might take a few days for some CUDA.jl changes for it to actually work for real...

Comment: @OscarSmith i tried the 1.10 beta... now cuda works fine but for some reason pyplot is broken... it creates a pyobject but no plot (.ipynb file). Im sorry i understand this is a completely different problem.. any input will be really helpful.